# In Assault on Arkham, why will the nano-bots cause their head to explode and not the whole body?

Tags: dc, suicide-squad, assault-on-arkham

In the [Batman: Assault on Arkham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Assault_on_Arkham) animated movie, they had explosives planted in their necks. In the movie, they drink nano-bots, but Flag says that his head will explode. Are the nano-bots a lie, and they surgically implanted something in their neck instead?

Evidence suggests The Joker is using the CPR electric pads to remove one, when he says "it really, really  hurts" (paraphrasing).

Or do the nano-bots grow into an explosive and move to the head?

Comment: They had something injected into their necks. Like really obviously with a big injector gun

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember from the film they have the explosives planted into their necks when they are strapped onto the wheelchairs.

I believe this is also shown later on with flashing lights on each characters neck.

Comment: Animated or live-action?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Live action

Comment: Ah. The question is about the animated feature.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I read the question as if it was comparing the animated movie to the live-action one